# Apply orElse on Boolean return value in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, conditional-statements

Having a method `def invoke(...): Boolean` I expected I could chain some error handling with `orElse` like this:

```
invoke(...) orElse (throw InvokeError(...))
```

Where the `orElse` part is executed if the return value of `invoke(...)` is `false`. Now I learned `orElse` is not a method of `Boolean`.

- Wouldn't it make sense to have `orElse` on the `Boolean` type?
- Is there a canonical systax to achieve the same semantic (except for `if (!invoke(...)) throw InvokeError(...)`)

Comment: Why don't you just throw an exception from within the method instead of evaluating the return type?

Comment: Sadly it's a library method.

Comment: And how about wrapping the method call with a custom method, throwing an exception if invoke fails?

Comment: Still I have to evaluate the return value of `invoke`. I thought having a `orElse` syntax would make that more readable (it's just a question of aesthetics).

Comment: I added an answer that might answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about just

```
invoke(...) || (throw InvokeError(...))
```

`||` is the logical `or`, which is short-circuited, meaning its second argument is lazily evaluated only when the first one is false.

That being said, it's probably more appropriate for your `invoke` method to return something more semantically meaningful, like an `Option` or a `Try`.

Comment: `||` is the semantic alternative I've been looking for! Still `orElse` would seem more readable to me. The `invoke` method is of a library by the way and defined as is.

Comment: Which scala version are you using? If I trie this code, I get a compilererror, telling me that this is an illegal start of simple expressions.

Comment: @T.Grottker, you need parenthesis around the throw, to make clear it's a value. My bad, just added them

Answer (score 2):

You can use `orElse` with a little bit of voodoo:

```
class RichBoolean(b: Boolean) {
  def orElse(f: (Boolean) => Unit) = f(b)
}

object RichBoolean {
  implicit def enrich(b: Boolean) = new RichBoolean(b)
}
```

Now you can use it the following way:

```
import RichBoolean._

val throwInvokeError = (b: Boolean) => if (!b) throw InvokeError(...)

invoke(...).orElse(throwInvokeError)
```

Comment: Somewhat strange definition of `orElse`. I think this one would be much more natural: `def orElse(f: => Unit) = if (!b) f`.

Comment: Well, feel free to use it that way. I just suggested this because it appealed to me.

Comment: I'm still wondering why `Boolean` itself is not "monadic" by default. Are there good reasons why it's missing in the scala-lib?